# Run a SQL query without parameters

Tags: sql, go

I'm using 'database/sql' module in Golang, trying to execute a query like:

```
select * from users
```

Note that it does not have any parameters. The method I'm using however forces you to have parameters in the arguments:

```
db.Query(query string, args)
```

So I'm forced to write something like:

```
db.Query("select * from users where 1=?", 1)
```

What's the way to run a query with no parameters?

Comment: Can't you just use `nil` in place of the args?

Comment: I tried, it throws an error.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `db.Query(query string, ...args interface{})`?  That is what the `database/sql` package uses: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query, and the `...` means it's variadic - you can pass any number of parameters, including 0.

Comment: not specifying any args worked. but it didn't like nil arg.

Comment: "The method I'm using however forces you to have parameters in the arguments" <-- No it doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[db.Query](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query):

> `func (db *DB) Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (*Rows, error)`
>
> Query executes a query that returns rows, typically a SELECT. The args are for any placeholder parameters in the query.

If you are really using the `database/sql` package, then the `args` parameter is [*variadic*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types):

> The final incoming parameter in a function signature may have a type prefixed with .... A function with such a parameter is called variadic and may be invoked **with zero or more arguments for that parameter**.

So, the way to do it is simply:

```
db.Query("select * from users")
```